# SplitContainer - Fixed Panel Height on Resize

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

every time I resize my form, panel2 get bigger, I want panel1 to get bigger and panel2's height to stay the same unless the user changes the splitterdistance themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the FixedPanel property:

```
splitContainer1.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel2;
```

Comment: That will still cause panel2 to resize instead of panel1.

Comment: @user3397642 How so?  I made Panel2 fixed, so it doesn't get resized.

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with c# itself?

Comment: @user3397642 Highly doubtful.  Try posting code that will reproduce the problem.  Chances are *something else* is causing the problem.

Comment: @user3397642 I can't duplicate the issue you describe.  I set the FixedPanel property to Panel2 and Panel2 does not get resized when adjusting the size of the control.  Only Panel1 does.